# In SE's "All Network Sites", what does "answered" statistic mean?

Tags: support, statistics, stackexchange.com

Does it mean have non-zero answers or does it mean have accepted answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [OK, Now Define “Answered”](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/), answered questions are those that have at least one answer with one upvote (or accepted).  Any other questions (with no upvoted or accepted answers) will appear in the Unanswered tab.

Comment: This is correct: unless otherwise indicated, "Unanswered" and "Answered" on all the sites follow this definition.